# How to create 2D visualization from Access data set

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a data set containing the following fields:

rack, rack_type, box_number, box_label, row, column

Each rack in the real world is basically a 2D grid with cells, each cell containing an object(a small box in this case). Each box will be associated with a specific position in the rack based on row and column. The size of the grid (number of rows/columns) is different based on rack_type

Is there a way to create a visual representation of these racks from the data supplied above? Specifically, I am looking to create a grid (as if you were looking at it in real life) where each cell shows some text--box_number and box_label in this case. I've been searching for hours on Google to no avail and I don't know if I'm even asking the question correctly. From what I can tell, the normal report/form features in Access do not support such a configuration of data. I'm wondering if there is some VBA solution, since I have some experience with VBA in Excel. Please let me know if this is incomprehensible gibberish.

Comment: I expect there is and probably will involve VBA. A similar application is building calendar in Access and filling each day 'cell' with info. Your question is too broad. Suggest you do research on Access calendar database template which might give you ideas for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If your racks has a **finite** maximum number of boxes in any configuration then you might consider this solution:

Let's say that any of your racks contains at most R boxes

1. create a form F
2. open F and add to it R text boxes B (they are not linked to anything)
3. save the form
4. now in VBA, on loading a rack you can iterate on each box and use some code to position each each of them on the form, show or hide it, and finally set its size!

Basically you've added to your form more boxes than a typical rack configuration would normally need, and by doing so you can hide some of them when not needed. You have this limit because you cannot create and add at runtime new text boxes to a form in VBA (it should work for reports too).

Note that you could use also other types of objects, text boxes are useful if you want to edit the text inside of them, otherwise you could use a label or anything that suits your needs the most (combo box... for example).

Basic methods that you might want to look at:

```
cell1.Height = 100
cell1.Visible = Not cell1.Visible
cell1.Move Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=400, Height:=3000
```

Anyhow if you get more in details, by giving some examples of your racks we might be able to come with a more detailed solution.